# New green leaf vegetable in the family. What is it called?

Tags: vegetables

[image: small cabbage-like veg with yellowing outer leaves. Teardrop-shaped with base being the bottom of the teardrop.]

Every week I get a box with regional vegetables, and this time this one came. I tried looking for cabbage, but I could not find anything similar. Do you know what is it? How is it cooked?

Comment: What does it look like when you remove the outer leaves?

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitzkohl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot like a sweetheart cabbage... it does not look very new though.

Comment: Or a smallish Napa cabbage. - Make some Kimchi !

Comment: Is there more than one thing called 'Napa cabbage'? The thing [Wiki shows under that name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napa_cabbage) is what I know as 'chinese leaves' and has little resemblance to the OP's item, which I would also identify as [Sweetheart cabbage](http://www.hub-uk.com/vegetables/pointed-cabbage.htm).

Comment: Napa cabbage has more of a bullet than a teardrop shape to it...

Answer (score 0):

This is a pointed cabbage, there are many varieties and it's hard to say which one. Cooking-wise they are in general not as tough as round cabbages, and a bit sweeter. You still prepare them as any other cabbage, just reduce the cooking time a bit. I personally think that boiling this type is a waste, I usually saute them.